# connect telegram bot with payment system

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot

I am trying to connect telegram bot and advcash sci , i need to insert this code :

```
'<form method="post" action="https://wallet.advcash.com/sci/"><input type="hidden" name="ac_account_email" value="***@gmail.com" /><input type="hidden" name="ac_sci_name" value="TradeCoinClub" /><input type="text" name="ac_amount" value="1.00" /><input type="text" name="ac_currency" value="USD" /><input type="text" name="ac_order_id" value="123456789" /><input type="text" name="ac_sign" value="2632cdb0af181f6e3136c2ac9f6c0268997bbf3de4a7e98ec6d982ad6fa43fce" /><!— Optional Fields —><input type="hidden" name="ac_success_url" value="http://tradecoin.cf/sucsess.html" /><input type="hidden" name="ac_success_url_method" value="GET" /><input type="hidden" name="ac_fail_url" value="http://tradecoin.cf/faild.html" /><input type="hidden" name="ac_fail_url_method" value="GET" /><input type="hidden" name="ac_status_url" value="http://tradecoin.cf/invest.html" /><input type="hidden" name="ac_status_url_method" value="GET" /><input type="text" name="ac_comments" value="Comment" /><input type="submit" /></form>'
```

This request must be sent using the client browser
The form with hidden fields is generated in the browser (interface) of my client.
The customer clicks on the button that sends the form and redirects it to the payment page.
i need to   Paste this HTML into my telegram bot with the html extension, useropen it in the browser and click the submit form button.
and after that bot  will be taken to the payment page.